# How to combine MYSQL query using the WITH Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database, with-statement

I can't figure out for the life of me how to go about in combining these two MYSQL query.  The only difference in the code below is that they are selecting separate fields and assigning them to separate aliases. I tried to use the WITH clause but haven't been able to figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
(
    SELECT TOP 1 ArticlePath 
    FROM [blog].[TBL_BlogArticles] suba WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN [blog].[TBL_BlogArticlesLanguages] subl WITH (NOLOCK) ON subl.LanguageCode = @LanguageCode AND subl.ArticleID = suba.ArticleID
    INNER JOIN [blog].[TBL_BlogArticleCategory] subac WITH (NOLOCK) ON subac.ArticleID = suba.ArticleID
    INNER JOIN [blog].[TBL_BlogCategories] subc WITH (NOLOCK) ON subc.CategoryID = subac.CategoryID
    WHERE subc.BlogID = @BlogID AND [TimeStamp] < l.[TimeStamp] AND Enabled = 1
    ORDER BY a.Priority DESC, [TimeStamp] DESC
) 
AS PreviousArticlePath,
(
    SELECT TOP 1 ArticleTitle 
    FROM [blog].[TBL_BlogArticles] suba WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN [blog].[TBL_BlogArticlesLanguages] subl WITH (NOLOCK) ON subl.LanguageCode = @LanguageCode AND subl.ArticleID = suba.ArticleID
    INNER JOIN [blog].[TBL_BlogArticleCategory] subac WITH (NOLOCK) ON subac.ArticleID = suba.ArticleID
    INNER JOIN [blog].[TBL_BlogCategories] subc WITH (NOLOCK) ON subc.CategoryID = subac.CategoryID
    WHERE subc.BlogID = @BlogID AND [TimeStamp] < l.[TimeStamp] AND Enabled = 1
    ORDER BY a.Priority DESC, [TimeStamp] DESC
) 
AS PreviousArticleTitle,
```

Comment: You sure you're not thinking of 'union' rather than with?

Comment: Does not look like MySQL

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to have it on the same row, just add SELECT, for example:

```
SELECT 1 AS PreviousArticlePath, 2 AS PreviousArticleTitle
```

Result

```
PreviousArticlePath PreviousArticleTitle
1                   2
```

1 and 2 will be your sub-query

For your query will be

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT TOP 1 ArticlePath 
      FROM [blog].[TBL_BlogArticles] suba WITH (NOLOCK)
     INNER JOIN [blog].[TBL_BlogArticlesLanguages] subl WITH (NOLOCK) ON subl.LanguageCode = @LanguageCode AND subl.ArticleID = suba.ArticleID
     INNER JOIN [blog].[TBL_BlogArticleCategory] subac WITH (NOLOCK) ON subac.ArticleID = suba.ArticleID
     INNER JOIN [blog].[TBL_BlogCategories] subc WITH (NOLOCK) ON subc.CategoryID = subac.CategoryID
     WHERE subc.BlogID = @BlogID AND [TimeStamp] < l.[TimeStamp] AND Enabled = 1
     ORDER BY a.Priority DESC, [TimeStamp] DESC
) AS PreviousArticlePath,
(
    SELECT TOP 1 ArticleTitle 
      FROM [blog].[TBL_BlogArticles] suba WITH (NOLOCK)
     INNER JOIN [blog].[TBL_BlogArticlesLanguages] subl WITH (NOLOCK) ON subl.LanguageCode = @LanguageCode AND subl.ArticleID = suba.ArticleID
     INNER JOIN [blog].[TBL_BlogArticleCategory] subac WITH (NOLOCK) ON subac.ArticleID = suba.ArticleID
     INNER JOIN [blog].[TBL_BlogCategories] subc WITH (NOLOCK) ON subc.CategoryID = subac.CategoryID
     WHERE subc.BlogID = @BlogID AND [TimeStamp] < l.[TimeStamp] AND Enabled = 1
     ORDER BY a.Priority DESC, [TimeStamp] DESC
) AS PreviousArticleTitle
```

Result

```
PreviousArticlePath      PreviousArticleTitle
"Some ArticlePath value" "Some ArticleTitle value"
```

Comment: What if the queries are already a sub-query?  I get `Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
`